# How to load into __m256 from a float* but reading backwards in memory as opposed to forwards?

Tags: c++, c, x86-64, intrinsics, avx

I've got an array of floats that I'd like to access in reverse order. In my non-vectorized code this is easy.

Here is a simplifed version of the data that I have.

```
float A[8] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
float B[8] = {s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z};
```

Here is the operation I would like to do.

```
float C[8] = {a*z, b*y, c*x, d*w, e*v, f*u, g*t, h*s};
```

I'd like to be able to do some kind of `load_ps` operation that will give me something like this:

```
__m256 A_Loaded         = _mm256_load_ps(&A[0]);
                        = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};

__m256 B_LoadedReversed = _mm256_loadr_ps(&B[7]);
                        = {z, y, x, w, v, u, t, s};

__m256 Output = _mm256_mul_ps(A_Loaded, B_LoadedReversed);
              = {a*z, b*y, c*x, d*w, e*v, f*u, g*t, h*s};
```

One of the data sources I have is a lookup table, so could be reversed if push comes to shove, but would much prefer to avoid that as that would compilcate other areas of the program.

I've currently got a botch workaround using `_mm256_set_ps()` and manually pointing to the data I need, but that is not as performative as I would like.

I know there is a 'reversed' `_mm256_set_ps()` (`_mm256_setr_ps()`), but there doesn't seem to be the `_mm256_loadr_ps()` that I need.

Any ideas and thoughts about this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never worked with these intrinsic functions, but I tried to do this manually while compiling with `-mavx` and looking at the [assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/7dahv1Y66), it _looks_ pretty ok. I've no idea how it compares to the assembly code when using the intrinsic functions though.

Comment: @Ted, in this case the reverse is no-operation. You have all zeros in local variable, so the compiler fully propagated the constants and replaced it all with just `xorps`. If you move away the floats from main to global, you'll see the compiler emitting code, and it is not as optimal as a shuffle would be.

Comment: @Ted, curious fact: in MSVC STL there's an optimization to explicitly implement `std::reverse` for trivial types with SSE2/AVX2 shuffles, here's 4-byte type version: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/vector_algorithms.cpp#L221-L259
So instead of relying on the compiler, there's explicit help from the library side.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I see, thanks! I don't have the toolkit to try it out myself. Looks nice. Oh, and cool MS optimization.

Comment: Terminology: "performative" is when you're on stage as an actor, for example.  You're looking for "performant".

Comment: Obviously storing your data in reversed order in the first place would be faster, so the question is trading off a `vpermd` here (or split loads -> `vpermilps` to avoid a vector constant), vs. more expensive index calculations in other parts of the program if that means they'd have to do `LUT[n-i]` instead of `LUT[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the order inside a `__m256` in two steps, using `_mm256_permute_ps` and `_mm_256_permute2f128_ps`.

- `_mm256_permute_ps` allows you to permute within each "lane", the high and low 128-bit chunks.
- `_mm_256_permute2f128_ps` allows you to permute 128-bit chunks across lanes.

It's something like this:

```c
__m256 b = _mm256_loadr_ps(&B[0]);
b = _mm256_permute_ps(b, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 2, 1, 0));
b = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(b, b, 1);
```

These instructions are documented in the Intel intrinsics guide: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html

### How does setr_ps work?

How does setr_ps() reverse things? It just reverses the arguments. Here's the version I pulled from my GCC installation:

```c
extern __inline __m256 __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_mm256_setr_ps (float __A, float __B, float __C, float __D,
                float __E, float __F, float __G, float __H)
{
  return _mm256_set_ps (__H, __G, __F, __E, __D, __C, __B, __A);
}
```

You can see, setr_ps() does not correspond to any underlying processor capability, it just reorders the arguments.

Comment: This is working for me with the following changes, thanks!
```
 __m256 b = _mm256_load_ps(&B[0]);
 b = _mm256_permute_ps(b, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 1, 2, 3));
 b = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(b, b, 1);
```

Comment: @JamiePond: If you can use AVX2, Alex's `vpermps` answer is more efficient; only one lane-crossing shuffle instead of separate lane-crossing and in-lane shuffles.  If you were going to use this AVX1 version, you'd probably want to do two separate 128-bit (`__m128`) loads as a `movups` / `vinsertf128` to feed your in-lane `vpermilps`, especially if older CPUs like Zen1 or Sandybridge are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can't express this as a load -- all loads are "forward".

You'll have to use a shuffling operation. Something that has "permute" or "shuf" in its name. Probably `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` is a good bet for your case, if AVX2 is available.  It gets all the work done in one shuffle instruction, although it does need to load a shuffle-control vector.  If only AVX1 is available, Dietrich's answer suggests a way to use two AVX1 shuffles.

Something like this (if I didn't get indexes reversed):

```c
// AVX2
__m256 B_LoadedReversed = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(
                              _mm256_load_ps(&B[0]),  // load B[0..7]
                              _mm256_set_epi32(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
```

One of the parameters of such functions is vector of indices, or for other shuffles like in-lane `_mm256_permute_ps` it is an 8-bit immediate value (imm8).

Each element of the parameter is the position of the source vector element in the destination vector. For imm8 there are 2 bit positions.

Some shuffling functions perform shuffle multiple times for subvectors of the given vectors, but not this one.

Many of the AVX+ shuffles don't shuffle across *lanes* (groups of 128 bits), but this one does.

Comment: Could you please provide a short example of how this might be used? I can't find documentation on that function that I can fully understand. E.g. how is the mask used, and how would it be used to tackle this problem? Would it be used to reverse the data after the load?

Comment: @JamiePond, elaborated

Comment: Drat, sorry, that's an AVX2 instruction, which I cannot support with this application. 
Do you know of any vanilla AVX alternatives?

Comment: @JamiePond see the other answer then, it is AVX only